# Обращение к HH API через AJAX

Tags: reactjs, axios

Приложение на React, нужно обратиться к [HH API](https://dev.hh.ru/) через AJAX (подключен axios), обращение идет на `onKeyUp`

```
handleKeywordsKeyUp(e) {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.hh.ru/?text='+e.target.value, 
            headers: { 
                'User-Agent': 'MyApp/1.0 (my-app-feedback@example.com)', 
                'HH-User-Agent': 'MyApp/1.0 (my-app-feedback@example.com)', 
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
            })
          .then(function (response) {
             //this.setState({autosearchresponse: response.data})
            console.log(1);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
```

Приложение запущено на локальном хосте http://localhost:3000/
В консоли вываливаются ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Не получается установить хедер `User-Agent`...

Comment: да вроде как написано у них сделано https://github.com/hhru/api/issues/215

Comment: Там ведь вконце написано: передавайте не `User-Agent`, а передавать `HH-User-Agent`. Ссылка: https://github.com/hhru/api/blob/master/docs/general.md#request-requirements

Comment: передаю же, он есть в списке хедеров. там и написано: Заголовки User-Agent и HH-User-Agent взаимозаменяемы, в случае, если вы отправите оба заголовка, обработан будет только HH-User-Agent.

Comment: Так у вас ошибка в том, что браузр не позволяет установить заголовок `User-Agent`. Не устанавливайте этот хедер, оставьте только `'HH-User-Agent': 'MyApp/1.0 (my-app-feedback@example.com)', `

Comment: Нет, это не влияет, та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74767/discussion-between-klimenkomud-and-heidel).